# Разработка расширений для хрома

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Например в Html странице есть это:

```html
<script>
  alert('hi');
</script>
```

Как с помощью расширения отменить выполнение этого скрипта?

Comment: Никак! Если его только физически не вырезать из страницы до построения Dom модели и запуска песочницы.

Comment: [Расширение Chrome для блокировки диалоговых окон](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549463/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-chrome-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD). Вопрос/ответ по вашей теме.

Comment: `<noscript>`? :D

Answer (score 1):

Вообще если у расширения есть доступ к окну, то делается просто, переназначаем функцию и все:

```
window.alert = function(){return false;}
```

Comment: Пробовал, этот скрипт запрещает alert в коде расширения, но не в коде страницы.
В манифесте в  "matches" указана ссылка на сайт. Этого достаточно?

Comment: Я года 3 расширений не писал, не знаю что изменилось, попробуйте так https://habrahabr.ru/post/186762/